# Errno::ECONNREFUSED in HomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi iam totally new in ruby and genieacs. Iam trying to setup genieacs in my local system. Iam getting  **Errno::ECONNREFUSED in HomeController#index** plesae check in screen shot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzKmM.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not use screen shots of error messages. Instead copy the relevant portions of the error message and paste them in your question. If you want debugging advice you need to [include a complete, minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be used to solve the problem. You can't just write "Waah, it does'nt work" and expect people to do all the legwork or find the answer from a crystal ball. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the gui without having raised the API daemon first. It is located on bin/genieacs-nbi under geniacs server (not GUI) directory.